# JAXB on JDK15: which jars are needed?

Tags: intellij-idea, jaxb, java-15

I work in intelliJIDEA with JDK15 without any Gradle, Maven or else.
Yes, we all know that JAXB is removed from JDK since JDK11.
So I tried to simply add some libs to the project as jar files:

```
    jaxb-runtime-3.0.0
    jaxb-impl-3.0.0
    jaxb-core-3.0.0
    jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.03592
    xmlbeans-2.6.02
    activation-1.0.22
```

Still, all I get is:

```
    javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
```

on this line:

```
    jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Hamster.class);
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mix-up of incompatible library versions: neither `jaxb-impl-3.0.0.jar` nor `jaxb-runtime-3.0.0.jar` is an implementation of JAXB API 2.4.0. There has been a breaking change between Java EE 8 specifications (like JAXB 2.4.0) and [Jakarta EE 9](https://jakarta.ee/release/9/) specifications (like JAXB 3.0): basically the package namespace `javax.` has been replaced with `jakarta.*`.

Therefore in order to use JAXB 3.0 you need:

- either [`jaxb-impl-3.0.0.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/3.0.0) from `com.sun.xml.bind` and its dependencies or [`jaxb-runtime-3.0.0.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/3.0.0) from `org.glassfish.jaxb` and its dependencies. The former has less dependencies (many minor dependencies were condensed into [`jaxb-core-3.0.0.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core/3.0.0); you shouldn't mistake it with the `org.glassfish.jaxb` artifact of the [same name](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-core/3.0.0)),
- to replace all `javax.xml.bind` with `jakarta.xml.bind` in your code.